# Can I use a symbol that has been previously redefined by the \renewcommand?

Tags: macros

I have a line
\renewcommand{\subset}{\subseteq}
in my document.
Now, out of all things, I need to use the symbol \subset. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First and foremost: Don’t redefine standard commands like `\subset` and `\alpha`. It’s bad style and will lead to confusion when collaborating with others, submitting papers to journals, or using external tools.

But if you absolutely must, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldsubset=\subset

\renewcommand{\subset}{\subseteq}

\begin{document}

\[
    A \oldsubset B
    \implies
    A \subset B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might note that this `\let` has to occur *before* `\subset` is redefined.